# Having issues with Heroku deployment

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack, heroku-cli

I am trying to upload a MEAN stack app for the first time, so I am not sure I am doing it the best way but here it is.

I have deployed my nodeJS server to one domain and it seems to be working fine - [response message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cZoi.png)

but I am having problems with the client part.

I deployed the angular code to a different domain (not sure if that's how you do it) and I am getting this error: 
[error link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26KCg.png)

Here is a link to my github project repository if it could provide some more information - https://github.com/igalM/igal-school

I used the Heroku CLI and Container Registry to upload the code with Dockerfile.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I just had to add a server.js to my client folder. SOLVED!